# iOS8 drawing rectangle not showing

Tags: ios, ios8

I have the below code to draw a datepicker (showing around the middle of the screen). It works in iOS 7 but in iOS 8 it is not showing. Only the "Select Expiry Date" is shown in a small box in the bottom of the screen.

```
    menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Expiry Date"
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    pickerView = [[CDatePickerViewEx alloc] init];
    CGRect pickerRect = pickerView.bounds;
    pickerRect.origin.y = 50;
    pickerRect.size.height = 100;
    pickerView.frame = pickerRect;

    UIButton *startbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    startbtn.frame = CGRectMake(240,12, 60, 25);
    [startbtn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [startbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [startbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedbuttonCancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [menu addSubview:pickerView];
    [menu addSubview:startbtn];
    [menu showInView:self];
    [menu setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320, 260)];
```

Comment: [“`UIActionSheet` is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy.”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html)  Now you know why.

Answer (score 0):

Check if AutoLayout is enabled for your view, as well as Size classes. I ran into a similar issue before and remember of fixing it with programmatic constraints.